# updating custom uiview's frame after adding subviews to it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am having a big mental block figuring out something I think easy. Please see this very short video: http://screencast.com/t/eaW7rbECv4Ne.

I would like to draw a rectangle in my layoutSubviews method around the whole area that covers the subviews. I currently draw yellow rect around each term as you can see in the video.

I have a StatementView. In each key tap I am creating  new objectView and adding it to my StatementView like below. I add the objectViews to a containerView and try to get the origin and size of the containerView in order to draw the stroke around it. However, it always gives me 0.

How should I update containerViews bounds values after I add the subviews to it?

```
//  Created by ilteris on 1/31/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 ilteris. All rights reserved.
@implementation QWZStatementView
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.textField = [[MyUITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
        self.textField.inputView   = [LNNumberpad defaultLNNumberpad];
        self.textField.delegate = self;
        self.isNumerator = NO;
        self.isDenominator = NO;
        [self addSubview:self.textField];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(statementOneTextFieldChanged:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];
        self.containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
        [self addSubview:self.containerView];
        self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        self.objectsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
        self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;            
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)statementOneTextFieldChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {   
    NSLog(@"statementOneTextFieldChanged");
    QWZObjectView *objectView = [[QWZObjectView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    [self.containerView addSubview:objectView];
    QWZTerm* term = [QWZQuestionDetailViewController createAndReturnCoreDataTermForJSONDict:objectData];
    [objectView createTerm:term];
    [self.objectsArray addObject:objectView];
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    NSLog(@"layoutSubviews StatementView");
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGSize totalSize  = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    for (QWZObjectView* objectView in self.objectsArray) {
        CGSize textSize = objectView.bounds.size;
        objectView.frame = CGRectMake(totalSize.width , totalSize.height, textSize.width , textSize.height);
        totalSize.width = textSize.width + totalSize.width;
    }
    CGRect bounds = self.containerView.bounds;
/*
    NSLog(@"self.containerView.bounds is %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.containerView.bounds)); //always 0. 
    bounds.origin = CGPointMake(totalSize.width/2, self.containerView.bounds.origin.y); //adding this code didn't help at all.
    CGFloat borderWidth = 2.0f;
    self.bounds = CGRectInset(self.bounds, -borderWidth, -borderWidth);
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
*/
    bounds.origin = CGPointMake(totalSize.width/2, self.containerView.bounds.origin.y);
    self.containerView.bounds = bounds;
}
@end
```

Comment: So, are you just looking for a way to draw text with a box around all of the text, rather than around each individual character? Have you thought about using a `UILabel`, using `sizeToFit` and playing with the properties of that label's `layer`? I.e., `self.label.layer.borderColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor; self.label.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;` Would something like that give you what you want? That seems easier than managing an array of views where 1 view == 1 character.

Comment: @mbm29414 No, that was for demonstration purposes. Ultimately what I am trying to figure out is this. I have an UIView. I add a containerView to this UIView as a subview. Then I add n number of subviews to this containerView. Now what's the proper way of getting the updated size of the containerView reflected from adding these subviews to it? I am aware  that we should treat views free from width/height and just as planes but then what's the proper way of getting the position of those subviews from the top view?

Comment: In other words, in every other platform I worked with, when I add subviews to parent view, parent view updates its bounds. Why isn't that the case with iOS platform? How do people approach this problem?

Comment: I think I got it. In iOS, there are 2 ways to calculate view frames: 1. Springs and Struts (old/manual), 2. AutoLayout (new/semi-automatic). Also, you can go "outside-in" or "inside-out". In your case, you seem to want to go "inside-out" by letting the subviews define their size, which determines the size of the container view (which may also then determine the size of the "main" `UIView`). But then, how is that "main" view positioned? What happens to it if it gets arbitrarily large? AutoLayout is fantastic, but you have to give it explicit instructions that can be resolved in all cases.

Comment: If you can give some more detail to the overall structure of this particular view hierarchy, I'll see what I can do to help.

Comment: So, I edited your code and noticed a few things. You're trying to access `bounds` for `self.containerView`. By default, `bounds` has an origin of `(0,0)`, so you probably want to be accessing `self.containerView.frame` instead.

Comment: @mbm29414 I am going with old-fashioned way here since I have very limited knowledge about autolayout. I am also used to using IB for layout in general and that's why I am having so much problems when things have to be created dynamically in the code.

Comment: @mbm29414 My view hierarchy is quite complicated unfortunately. I have one big statementView in the viewcontroller  which holds objectViews. ObjectViews could have different types as fractions, subscripts, variables. The Objects that have one terms such as "a" are easy. But some of them such as fraction could have multiple terms such as "a+b/2+1". so this whole thing should be centered in the mainViewController at all times. You can see I am almost there in the video. I am just having a hard time figuring out this inside/Out logic. Can you describe in layman terms how that works please?

Comment: Yup, I am aware of the bounds origin giving 0,0 but I am interested in  updated width, height which also gives me 0,0 unfortunately.

Comment: For one thing, I don't see where you ever set the height of `bounds`. Am I missing it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70973/discussion-between-ilteris-and-mbm29414).